# How to create one dataframe from a list whose elements are lists containing one dataframe each in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, transform, r-sf

I am trying to build a dataframe of KML files. I have 52 different files in my dataset, and I have already uploaded them to R using the following code chunk:

```
#importing data
library(fs)
file_paths = fs::dir_ls("C:/Users/JoaoArbache/Desktop/Mestrado/carbono/dados")
file_contents = list()

for(i in seq_along(file_paths)) {
  file_contents[[i]] = st_read(
    dsn  = file_paths[[i]]
  )
}

#renaming the lists
numeros = list()
for(i in file_paths) {
  numeros[[i]] = str_extract(i, "\\d+") %>% 
                   as.numeric()
}
id = do.call(rbind.data.frame, numeros) %>% 
    filter(!row_number() %in% c(53))
colnames(id)[1] = "id"

file_contents = set_names(file_contents, id$id)
```

Ok, so far everything is alright. I have all of the 52 files uploaded in the `file_contents` list.
[This is the file_contents list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpy7r.png)
Now, I need to get each of the 52 lists in `file_contents`, that contain one dataframe each, and build a single dataframe. So it should bind 52 different dataframes into a single one. I`ve tried lots of different ways to solve this problem, but I always failed.

Thanks for the support :)

I tried different loops, `do.call` function, some native R functions, but none of them worked. I`d either get an error message (e.g.

```
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = as.data.frame(i)) : 
  attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

) or just create a dataframe with the first element of the `file_contents` list. I was expecting to get a single dataframe with the 52 dataframes binded...

Comment: Try `dplyr::bind_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(file_contents, use.names = T, fill = T)
```

That assumes the col names are the same if they are not set use.names = F.

Comment: I did, but I got this error message:
``` Error in rbindlist(file_contents, use.names = T, fill = T) : 
  Class attribute on column 3 of item 2 does not match with column 3 of item 1. ```
There are some attributes that are Polygons and others are Multipolygons, so this is messing things up.

Comment: @jparbache - can you include a small subset of your list that would include the above and any other error you've come across thus far?

Comment: What would a small subset of the list be? You want the data? Here`s a link with a small sample: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uxuaRKo6_PPoXvBU6aZ_4yWYQAsHGLTl?usp=sharing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You can reference that as an example. Basically just providing a snippet of your dataset using either `dput` or some code that builds the basic structure of your list that will error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr::map` on a list of files and build a single dataset if all of the files are regularly shaped (have the same columns).  Below is an example using the `nc` dataset included with the `sf` package.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr) 
library(purrr)

# make a temporary directory for the example
temp_dir <- tempdir()

# read nc data 
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# create two datasets with all the same columns, but different data
one <- nc[1:3,] 
two <- nc[55,]

# write two separate kml objects to disk
st_write(one, paste0(temp_dir, "/", "one.kml"))
#> Writing layer `one' to data source `/tmp/RtmpfRjSGc/one.kml' using driver `KML'
#> Writing 3 features with 14 fields and geometry type Multi Polygon.
st_write(two, paste0(temp_dir, "/", "two.kml"))
#> Writing layer `two' to data source `/tmp/RtmpfRjSGc/two.kml' using driver `KML'
#> Writing 1 features with 14 fields and geometry type Multi Polygon.

# show the files on disk, just for illustration
list.files(path = temp_dir, pattern = "*.kml", full.names = T)
#> [1] "/tmp/RtmpfRjSGc/one.kml" "/tmp/RtmpfRjSGc/two.kml"

# read the two files & make them one dataframe:
together <- temp_dir %>%
  list.files(pattern = "*.kml", full.names = T) %>%
  map_dfr(st_read)
#> Reading layer `one' from data source `/tmp/RtmpfRjSGc/one.kml' using driver `LIBKML'
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 24 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -81.74091 ymin: 36.23402 xmax: -80.43509 ymax: 36.58977
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> Reading layer `two' from data source `/tmp/RtmpfRjSGc/two.kml' using driver `LIBKML'
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 24 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -83.259 ymin: 35.29087 xmax: -82.74374 ymax: 35.79195
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

head(together)
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 24 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -83.259 ymin: 35.29087 xmax: -80.43509 ymax: 36.58977
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>        Name description timestamp begin  end altitudeMode tessellate extrude
#> 1      Ashe        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>         <NA>         -1       0
#> 2 Alleghany        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>         <NA>         -1       0
#> 3     Surry        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>         <NA>         -1       0
#> 4   Haywood        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>         <NA>         -1       0
#>   visibility drawOrder icon  AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID
#> 1         -1        NA <NA> 0.114     1.442  1825    1825 37009  37009        5
#> 2         -1        NA <NA> 0.061     1.231  1827    1827 37005  37005        3
#> 3         -1        NA <NA> 0.143     1.630  1828    1828 37171  37171       86
#> 4         -1        NA <NA> 0.144     1.690  1996    1996 37087  37087       44
#>   BIR74 SID74 NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                       geometry
#> 1  1091     1      10  1364     0      19 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47258 3...
#> 2   487     0      10   542     3      12 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.2397 36...
#> 3  3188     5     208  3616     6     260 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45612 3...
#> 4  2110     2      57  2463     8      62 MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.74374 3...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This kinda works, but when I try to open the dataframe, i get the following error message:
Error in CPL_get_z_range(obj, 2) : z error - expecting three columns;

Comment: @jparbache All of your files in the sample data posted are not regular, they have different columns.  You will have to clean the data to make them all similar before combining them into a single dataset. Additionally, you may need to use `st_zm` on some of them to remove the z values from the geometry columns.